# Linq query using include has too many rows

Tags: entity-framework, linq

[image]

I am having an issue getting the records I need from 1 query using the include extension.

This is what is mostly working:

```
_db.Companies.Where(x => x.CompanyID == id)
                .Include(x => x.Contact)
                .Include(x => x.Properties.Select(p => p.Contact))
                .Include(x => x.Properties.Select(f => f.Facilities.Select(c => c.Contact)))
                .Include(x => x.Properties.Select( => f.Facilities.Select(s => s.Sections.Select(si => si.SectionIdeas))))
                .SingleOrDefault();
```

This is fine except entity initiates a separate query for each license since I am not including it.

Since I would like to get the license in the same query I tried this:

```
_db.Companies.Where(x => x.CompanyID == id)
                .Include(x => x.Contact)
                .Include(x => x.Properties.Select(p => p.Contact))
                .Include(x => x.Properties.Select(f => f.Facilities.Select(c => c.Contact)))
                .Include(x => x.Properties.Select(f => f.Facilities.Select(l => l.Licenses)))//added
                .Include(x => x.Properties.Select(f => f.Facilities.Select(s => s.Sections.Select(si => si.SectionIdeas))))
                .SingleOrDefault();
```

This causes another row to be returned for each facility. Is there a way to get the license without additional rows?

Comment: I am unclear what you mean by Row? It should return a Company Object? Have you considered/tried `.ThenInclude`??

Comment: What I mean by row is if I look at SQL Profiler and copy the query that is being sent to SQL from Entity and run it manually, I get an additional record returned for each facility which contains the license data. Yes looking at the object I just see the Company but I wanted to know if there was a way to structure the linq to get the data without the extra rows returned. I can do the join in SQL directly and get the license without extra rows.

Comment: ThenInclude is only available in EF core I think and I am using 6 but I will look at it.

Comment: EF is very powerful but you can't expect like for like SQL to come out :) I can't see anything wrong with your query or table structure, that might be something you will have to live with.

Comment: Heberda, thanks for your comments.